# Magento 2.3 Web Setup Wizard Blank

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I got a blank page (to be exact, there is a navigator background bar) when go to System -> Web Setup Wizard in Magento 2.3.2 Admin Panel.

I checked via the development tool of chrome, and found those 403 response

```
GET http://mysite/setup/index.php/navigation 403 (Forbidden)
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"Access denied.\n","status":403,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"index.php/navigation","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Cache-Control":"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate","Pragma":"no-cache","Expires":0}},"statusText":"Forbidden","xhrStatus":"complete"}

GET http://mysite/setup/index.php/navigation/side-menu 403 (Forbidden)
GET http://mysite/setup/index.php/navigation/header-bar 403 (Forbidden)
POST http://mysite/setup/index.php/session/prolong 403 (Forbidden)
```

It looks like there's something to do with the permission. I checked all my directories under /setup but should be all ok

My nginx configuration is as below,

```
root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        #deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}
```

I searched on the web but found no answer. Any hint will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what's the reason, the index.php did not have an execute privilege. So add it:

```
chmod +x setup/index.php
```

Solved the problem.